# input textfield with button on the right and not stacked in mobile using bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, position

I am trying to achieve this effect for some time but no success. Need the button of the search form on the right side of the textfield in both desktop and mobile view using bootstrap classes. Th button always comes up on the bottom of the textfield no matter what i do. I need both textfield + button to be centered in both desktop and mobile view.

```
<header class="jumbotron masthead mastheadcstm">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row-fluid">
      <div class="offset3 span6 offset3">
        <form>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Engineer etc etc">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Search!</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/aYrjw/)**

**CSS**

```
  .offset3{
        text-align:center;
    }
```

Comment: I Tried this but doesn't seems to be working. I am using bootstrap and something pre existing css is preventing it to work. Works fine without bootstrap like its doing demo.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to force the needed rule "above" the others by using more class names, attributes and ids in the rule:

```
.jumbotron.masthead.mastheadcstm form{
    text-align:center;
}
```

or simply by adding the *!important* keyword to the property:

```
.jumbotron form{
    text-align:center !important;
}
```

Both these methods rise the specificity of the property, which should make it override the corresponding property within the rules-competitors.

---

Or you could try to find the culprit using Firefox with Firebug (you'll need to install this extension) or Google Chrome console (press F12 to activate it).